# Using lzip with Svelte

Tags: svelte, lzip

I have a string that I wish to compress in Svelte and to expand later in python. I am have problems importing lzip into Svelte

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "lzip": "^1.0.10",
    ...
}
```

**App.Svelte**

```
<script>
    import lzip from 'lzip.js';
    ...
```

I get the console message:

```
ReferenceError: lzip is not defined
```

And in the npm terminal

```
(!) Missing global variable name
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
lzip.js (guessing 'lzip')
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the [`lzip` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lzip) you specified is what you want.

It is completely obscure and contains nothing but a `bin` script that does not export anything. It is thus not suitable for import anyway.

`lzip` itself does not sound like the correct choice either.

> lzip is a free, command-line tool for the compression of data

You can't use a command line tool in the front end. If anything you have to install that on the server and only use on the server, definitely not in a `.svelte` file.

There are many other libraries that just compress data directly, so I doubt that you need `lzip` for that.

Comment: Ok. Any recommendations?

Comment: I have used [`jszip`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jszip) before.

Comment: my string is not in a file; [lz-string](https://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html)?

Comment: Possibly, StackOverflow does not allow questions that ask for recommendations; you will just have to do your own research into finding something suitable for your requirements.

Comment: (The string does not have to be in a file either, I only ever used `jszip` to generate ZIP files directly from memory. Of course you do end up with a ZIP archive containing files, which would need to be unwrapped again.)

Comment: got it working with lz-string - now to decompress using python ...